# Did this shot from Orville rely on cloning (image manipulation techniques)?

Tags: costume, special-effects, the-orville

This shot from *The Orville*

[image]

required a very large number of extras and costumes for a relatively low-budget venture.   (I'm mostly concerned with cost in the wardrobe department.)

Were that many uniforms produced and extras assembled or were the people cloned or composited from multiple shots reusing the same extras and/or costumes (or other effects)?

Comment: Wouldn't cloning dozens of humans be prohibitively expensive, not to mention illegal?

Comment: @Valorum, At least in the USA, there are no federal laws against the cloning of humans.Currently it is banned in 15 states though. Depending on where they were cloned, it could be a perfectly legal "enterprise"

Comment: But this is in the future so cloning would probably be legal.

Comment: Well, I imagine the in-universe explanation for [the repeated characters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175683/3823) *could* be cloning, for all we know!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Image cloning and compositing. You can see a bunch of duplicated people, and that's just at a quick look.

[image]

Comment: -1 for not drawing freehand circles! (not really)

Comment: I think I can see the at least one composite line now.   If you look at the black man in red just to the left of your second and third rightmost circle you can see and an unnatural light highlight around him.  And the white guy in gray to the left of him has the same thing.   This is the break between the foreground shot and the background, I believe.

Comment: Now I can't stop finding clones.